# How to merge two objects, overriding null values?

Tags: javascript, merge, lodash

I'd like to merge two similar but not identical objects and override null values in one of them, if such exist. For example I'd have these two objects:

```
const obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: '',
    c: [],
    d: null
}

const obj2 = {
    a: 2,
    b: null,
    d: 1
}
```

And the effect of merge should be:

```
const objMerged = {
    a: 2,
    b: '',
    c: [],
    d: 1
}
```

In other words, the most important source of data in the merged object is `obj2` but it lacks some properties from `obj1`, so they need to be copied and also some of the `obj2` values are `null` so they should be taken from `obj1` as well.

EDIT
I tried:

```
_.extend({}, obj1, obj2)
```

and

```
Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)
```

Comment: have you tried anything before asking?

Comment: Yes, Object.assign and the lodash extend function.

Comment: can you include your attempts in the question

Comment: Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

Comment: please edit the question with both of your attempts

Comment: What about removing "null" value first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith), and in the merge callback only take the 2nd value if it's not `null`:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: '', c: [], d: null }
const obj2 = { a: 2, b: null, d: 1 }

const result = _.mergeWith({}, obj1, obj2, (o, s) => _.isNull(s) ? o : s)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14):

You could also mix and match with [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and lodash `_.omitBy`:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: '', c: [], d: null }
const obj2 = { a: 2, b: null, d: 1 }

const result = {..._.omitBy(obj1, _.isNull), ..._.omitBy(obj2, _.isNull)}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You could also do it with ES6 only like this:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: '', c: [], d: null }
const obj2 = { a: 2, b: null, d: 1 }

let omitNull = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] === null).forEach(k => delete(obj[k]))
  return obj
}

const result = { ...omitNull(obj1), ...omitNull(obj2) }

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to this list of good answers, here's a recursive solution that will work with nested structures.

This example will merge the common properties of the `dst` object to the `src` object in all levels of nesting, leaving any properties that are not common intact.

```js
const merge = (dst, src) => {
  Object.keys(src).forEach((key) => {
    if (!dst[key]) {
      dst[key] = src[key];
    } else if (typeof src[key] === 'object' && src[key] !== null && typeof dst[key] === 'object' && dst[key] !== null) {
      merge(dst[key], src[key]);
    }
  });
},

/* Usage: */

src = {
  prop1: '1',
  prop2: {
    val: 2,
  }
},
dst = {
  prop1: null,
  prop2: {
    val: null,
  },
  prop3: null,
};

merge(dst, src);
console.log(dst);
```

Comment: Great answer. I really like this solution!

Comment: Great except I recommend `if (dst[key] == null)` instead b/c an integer of 0 would get replaced even though it's not null.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure JS based solution:

Iterate through the first object to replace values from second object, then add the additional values from the second object.

```js
const obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: '',
    c: [],
    d: null
}

const obj2 = {
    a: 2,
    b: null,
    d: 1
}

function mergeObjs(obj1, obj2){
  const merged = {}
  keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  keys1.forEach(k1 => {
     merged[k1] = obj2[k1] || obj1[k1]; // replace values from 2nd object, if any
  })
  Object.keys(obj2).forEach(k2 => {
     if (!keys1.includes(k2)) merged[k2] = obj[k2]; // add additional properties from second object, if any
  })
  return merged
}


console.log(mergeObjs(obj1, obj2))
```

Comment: merged[k2] = obj[k2] needs to be merged[k2] = obj2[k2]

Answer (score 2):

Using Lodash by [`create()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#create) and [`omitBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omitBy)

```js
const obj1 = {"a":1,"b":"","c":[],"d":null}

const obj2 = {"a":2,"b":null,"d":1}

const objMerged = _.create(
  _.omitBy(obj1, _.isNull),
  _.omitBy(obj2, _.isNull)
)

console.log(objMerged)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in only the first level of the two objects you could do something like this:

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: '',
  c: [],
  d: null
}

const obj2 = {
  a: 2,
  b: null,
  d: 1
}

const merged = Object.keys(obj1).concat(Object.keys(obj2)) // create an array that contains the keys of the two objects.
  .filter((k, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(k) === i) // remove duplicate keys
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c] = obj1[c] !== null ? obj1[c] : obj2[c];
    return a;
  }, {});

console.log(merged);
```

This example only check for `null` values, you should probably extend it to check for others like `undefined`, empty strings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You did it the good way using `Object.assign`, just remove what you don't want right before

```
Object.keys(obj1).forEach( k => {
    if ( obj1[k] //write the condition you want
        delete obj1[k]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var objMerged  = {};
for (var kobj1 in obj1) {
    for (var kobj2 in obj2) {
        if (obj1[kobj1] == null && obj2[kobj1] != null)
            objMerged[kobj1] = obj2[kobj1];
        else if (obj2[kobj2] == null && obj1[kobj2] != null)
            objMerged[kobj2] = obj1[kobj2];

    }
}
```

//Print objMerged to display