# Can't implement simple optional chaining

Tags: javascript, react-redux, javascript-objects, optional-chaining

I am trying to implement a simple optional chaining state update. What I want is for the items to ONLY be changed IF the item is defined/exists; if not/is undefined, I want the item to keep the previous state (e.g userID should remain = 2 if not updated).

To test this out I created an object with three variables:

```js
const userObj = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  userID: 2,
};
```

Then I created a function to update state:

```js
const updateState = (item) => {
  return {
    userObj.firstName = item?.firstName,
    userObj.lastName = item?.lastName,
    userObj.userID = item?.userID,
  };
};
```

Finally I pass the item which contains only one item to update (firstName) and I call the function:

```js
const item = {
  firstName: "None",
};

console.log(updateState(item));
```

The output:

```sh
 userObj.firstName = item?.firstName,
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

But when I hover over `userObj` I can see its properties:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two objects, overriding null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188121/how-to-merge-two-objects-overriding-null-values)

Comment: What’re you trying to return? A fresh object, or do you simply want to update the `userObj` object?

Comment: I will user this for updating Redux state which is immutable, but I just want to understand how I can update state regardless of mutability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *null coalescing* in conjunction with optional chaining:

```
const updateState = item => ({
  userObj.firstName = item?.firstName ?? userObj.firstName ,
  userObj.lastName  = item?.lastName  ?? userObj.lastName  ,
  userObj.userID    = item?.userID    ?? userObj.userId    ,
});
```

You could use the *spread operator*:

```
const updateState = item => {
  userObj = { ...userObj, ...item };
  return userObj;
}
```

Or you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com)'s [`defaults()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaults) function:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const updateState = item => {
  userObj = _.defaults(userObj, item)
  return userObj;
}
```

Or... if you really want to mutate the state object, rather than creating a new one and replacing it, roll your own, similar:

```js
const updateState = item => {
  for (const key in item ) {
    const hasValue = key != null && key != undefined && key != NaN ;

    if ( hasValue ) {
      userObj[prop] = item[prop];
    }

  }
}
```

There is, as they say, more than one way to skin a cat.

[**Edited:** Add explanation of the *spread* operator]

The spread operator,

```
const obj = { ...obj1, ...obj2, . . . , ...objN };
```

is somewhat akin to calling a function like this:

```
const obj = mergeObjects( obj1, obj2, . . ., objN );
```

where `mergeObjects()` is defined as:

```
function mergeObjects(...objects) {
  const mergedObject = {};

  for (const obj of objects ) {
    for (const key in obj ) {
      mergedObject[key] = item[key];
    }
  }

  return mergedObject;
}
```

Or perhaps a better explanation might be done using `Object.assign()`. One could say that an expression like:

```
const obj = {
  
  prop1: 'a' ,
  prop2: 'b' ,
  
  ...obj1    ,
  
  prop3: 'c' ,
  prop4: 'd' ,
  
  ...obj2    ,
  
  prop5: 'e' ,
  prop6: 'f' ,
  
  ...obj3    ,
  
}
```

is the equivalent of this:

```
const obj = Object.assign( {},
  {
    prop1: 'a' ,
    prop2: 'b' ,
  },
  obj1 ,
  {
    prop3: 'c' ,
    prop4: 'd' ,
  } ,
  obj2 ,
  {
    prop5: 'e' ,
    prop6: 'f' ,
  } ,
  obj3 ,
);
```

Comment: Null coalescing did not work for some reason. Got the same error. The spread operator worked perfectly. I understand that it copies both objects, but how does it update each key correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because what you are trying to return is an object with dots in its keys.

You're mixing assignment and object creation. In addition `item?.firstName` only helps with the case that `item` is null or undefined in a sense that it fails fast instead of throwing an exception because you can't access `null.firstName`.

For this kind of default you'd have to do something along the lines of `typeof item.firstName === 'string' ? item.firstName : userObj.firstName`.

To pull everything together:

```js
const func = (value, fallback) => (
  typeof value === typeof fallback
    ? value
    : fallback
);

const updateState = (item) => {
  userObj.firstName = func(item?.firstName, item.firstName);
  userObj.lastName = func(item?.lastName, item.lastName);
  userObj.userID = func(item?.userID, item.userId);

  return userObj;
};
```

Note however that this function will mutate `userObj`.

Edit: `default` was a poor naming choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, using javascript object destructuring

```
const updateState = (item) => {
 return {
   ...userObj,
   ...item,
 };
};
```

so it will only update the key and value that was passed, i hope the question is not on typescript